# Django -when i update datefields and choicefield i can t see curent value

Tags: python, django

I want to edit something but some fields don t fill with the current selected value. exemple: DateField and ModelChoiceField

This is my current code

views.py

```
def pacient_update(request, pk):
instance = get_object_or_404(Pacient.objects.filter(medic=request.user.medic), pk=pk)
instance_a = get_object_or_404(AdresaUseri, pk=pk)
pacient = PacientForm(request.POST or None, instance=instance)
adresa = AdresaForm(request.POST or None, instance=instance_a)

if pacient.is_valid() and adresa.is_valid():
instance  = pacient.save(commit=False)
instance.save()
instance_a = adresa.save(commit=False)
instance_a.save()
context = {
'instance':instance,
'form': pacient,
'form_a': adresa,
}
return render(request, 'pacienti/adaugare.html', context)
```

Comment: I found the problem with the datefields but the problem with ModelChoiceFiled is still there

Comment: How do you define your form?

Comment: you should show the model and form where the `ModelChoiceField` is defined. And when you say "some fields don't fill with the current selected value", you mean they are not displayed correctly in the initial HTML form, before submitting? Or they are not saved  correctly with the selected value from the form, after submitting?

Comment: i found the problem. it was in modelform... i had the respective fields in 'exclude' and this is the reason that was not working. but now is everything ok.
thanks for help